# Why is my plug socket CRACKLING?

Tags: wiring, plug, socket

I have one socket at my resident where I plug my laptop charger. It started crackling a few days ago and it continued every day since. Today I opened the socket and replaced it with a new one. It started working fine, but out of curiosity I opened it and found some burnt area.

Also, I found similar burnt spots in my plug as well and the plug was becoming hot after a few minutes.

The wiring is almost 8 years old and we have a very stable voltage flow. I keep this switch on almost 24/7 with a few hours of a gap in a week.

What was the reason behind this incident? Is a faulty plug I inserted the reason of this? Or is it because of the socket and not the plug?

[image]

Comment: Get an electrician.

Comment: Yes changed this myself right now and its working fine, do I still need to get one?

Comment: If you suspect something is wrong with your wiring, get an electrician. It's likely this was just the outlet itself being worn out, but if you think at all that there could be something wrong with the wiring in your house, you should have a professional look at it--you don't want to find out the hard way. The hard way involves your house burning down.

Comment: will definitely call an electrician for this , but keeping this socket in use for hours and days without no break in between can be reason?

Comment: Migrate to DIY.SE?

Answer (score 1):

It's one of those problems that will naturally get worse once it's started.  Every time you unplug the power supply, it creates a little arc, which burns away a speck of metal.

Eventually, the contacts start to get more and more burnt, and make poor contact.  Which causes more arcing and more burning.

Replacing the socket becomes the best option.  Check the plug too.  If that's damaged, look for a replacement lead for the laptop.

Comment: lead of the laptop is little burnt, just a small tip,not much.